# How can two tabs communicate inside a browser?

Tags: javascript

How can prepare a communication channel to communicate between multiple opened tabs in same browser without any server side support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Window/postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

You can also use `Window.localStorage` and register a [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent) and react on it from another tab.
Here's an interesting read: [Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API);

**EXAMPLE** using **localStorage** and the **StorageEvent**

Put this into `page1.html`

```
<button>CLICK ME TO CHANGE "A" - "B"</button>
<script>
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  localStorage.ab = localStorage.ab ===  "A" ? "B" : "A";
});
</script>
```

and this into `page2.html`

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("storage", function( StorageEvent ){
  console.log( StorageEvent );
  alert(StorageEvent.newValue);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also leverage Web-Sockets to achieve real-time event based commincation across tab's and browsers. Libraries such as [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) make the entire process very straightforward.